# How to set tablespace for a specific CREATE TABLE [Table] AS

Tags: sql, postgresql, tablespace

How to set **tablespace** for a specific table creation AS clause?, like:

```
CREATE TABLE [New Table] AS 
TABLE [Old Table] 
--WITH NO DATA
;
```

In which tablespace new table with/without data is created  for this specific 'AS' clause?

In official documentation, have not found such case:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html
, though it says:

> Tablespaces
>
> The PostgreSQL concept of tablespaces is not part of the standard.
> Hence, the clauses TABLESPACE and USING INDEX TABLESPACE are
> extensions.

So, please help me out, what is default tablespace will be used in such "AS" creation case of the table, and how to specify custom table space for this. By ALTER -ing created table?, like only:

```
ALTER TABLE [New Table] 
SET TABLESPACE [Existing Tablespace];
```

Comment: "*what is default tablespace will be used*"  - the same as for all other tables that don't specify a tablespace: the default tablespace which is the directory that was created uring `initdb`. Your second statement is the correct way to change the tablespace of an existing table. Note that tablespaces are rarely used in Postgres. Are you sure you need them?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but what if data will be moved from originated table with huge-disk-space-tablespace to new table with default tablespace, that has limited disk-space-tablespace? Is it ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html) you can append the `tablespace` option to a `CREATE TABLE AS` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table 
TABLESPACE custom_tablespace
AS 
TABLE old_table
WITH NO DATA;
```